# Why has the symbol "/:" been deprecated

Tags: scala

Since moving to scala 2.12.10 I am getting warnings in my code telling me symbol "/:" is deprecated and I should use foldLeft instead.

Why has it been deprecated? I would have thought this will make for more cumbersome code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of an effort to simplify Scala. [Here is what Martin Odersky had to say about it](https://scala-lang.org/blog/2016/01/02/new-year-resolutions.html):

> Another example, where I have doubts if not regrets are the /: and :\ operators in scala.collections. They are cute synonyms for folds, and I am still fond of the analogy with falling dominoes they evoke. But in retrospect I think maybe they did give a bad example for others to go overboard with symbolic operators.

Here is the pr deprecating it: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4893.
Also some further discussion occurred here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9607